# R Error in Ave and Memory Size

Tags: r, aggregate

I have some problems in R.

I would like to aggregate the column "Product.Family" in my data frame and then the aggregated value should be written to the specific row.
I have many data frames in a list and it should work for each of them.
Here is an example:

```
    x <- data.frame("Product.Family"=c("Family1","Family2","Family3","Family1","Family1","Family3","Family2"),
                "Value"=c(2,3,3.5,2.8,1.7,3.8,2.2))
dfList<-list(rep(x,7))

match <- function(df) {
  df$Avg.Product.Family <- ave(df$Value,df$Product.Family,FUN=mean)
}
dfList_new <- lapply(dfList, match)
```

I get the error

```
 Error in split.default(x, g) : first argument must be a vector
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

My other problem is, that I would like to calculate some raises between values. There are many NA´s and actually I can´t post a minimal example here because the error

```
    Error: cannot allocate vector of size 183 Kb In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 16326Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 16326Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  Reached total allocation of 16326Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

occurs only when I have very big data frames.
But the idea is to create a vector without NA´s for every row and calculate the change in percent between the first and last value.
This is my code:

```
    idc2 <- function(x) {
  xx <- x[!is.na(x)]
  ch=(xx[length(xx)]-xx[1])/xx[1]
}
i.d.crease2 <- function(df) {
  d <- as.matrix(df[,-c(1:12)])
  cbind(df, t(apply(d, 1, idc2)))
}
dfList_neu2 <- lapply(dfList2, i.d.crease2)
```

May there be a smarter solution, so that it runs without any errors?

Comment: Your first function works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: I expected this when I wrote it, but still I get this error...